# removeAttr(href) from ajax dynamic loaded navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to remove href attribute from certain navigation links when screen size is less than 768px. The navigation is dynamically generated with ajax and takes some time to load. I'm trying the following code but it is not working, but it works when the navigation is static(not ajax).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $("#main-navigation > li.dropdown > a").removeAttr("href");
  }
});
```

Thanks for some help

Comment: Can you provide some more details with code?

Comment: That code would run as soon as the page is loaded and the DOM is ready, not when your ajax content is loaded. You need to run your code after you have loaded your content, ie in the ajax success callback

Comment: Put that code in ajax success or complete event, if thats the case.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep track resize.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $("#main-navigation > li.dropdown > a").removeAttr("href");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Actually this is correct typical approach. Could be optimized but still should not be downvoted.

Comment: Thank you, at least someone supports:)

Comment: If you remove the attributes whenever the window resizes, you _should_ also be able to restore the links in case the window size becomes large enough (removal kind of removes this option). If the browser window is not resized and is not at least 768px wide, the resize event may or may not occur, so you at least should invoke the `resize` once yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with pure CSS solution to disable link "funtionality" on narrow screens (IE10+ at the time of writing):

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #main-navigation > li.dropdown > a {
    -ms-pointer-events: none;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to modify the DOM, you are probably better off with a 'live' event in combination with a media-query in CSS to style the unwanted links.

For example:

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '#main-navigation > li.dropdown > a', function(event) {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #main-navigation > li.dropdown > a {
    /*  remove unwanted styling  */
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

This would greatly reduce the performance overhead of the targeted resolution (< 768 seems to imply mobile users, for who the processing powers of the device may be limited).